# eToken java keytool certificates

Tags: java, linux, certificate, keytool

I'm using eToken in Linux and I need to view certificates stored on eToken in JAVA. I have been searching for tools and I found keytool, but If I use this howto, keytool shows me that there is 0 certs.

in **keytool-etoken.cfg** I have:

```
  name = eToken
  library = /usr/lib/libeTPkcs11.so
```

**command:**

```
keytool -list -keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11 -providerClass sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11  -providerArg keytool-etoken.cfg
```

**output:**

```
Enter keystore password:  

Keystore type: PKCS11
Keystore provider: SunPKCS11-NSS

Your keystore contains 0 entries
```

What should I do to see and use certs on eToken? In Firefox or Chrome it works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the solution is to install SafeNet Authentication client 8.X (SAC). Than java 1.6 will work with token and even with keytool command. But the problem is, that openoces is old and not developed anymore and It cannot read certificates from Token(java) even it has support for it (thru pkcs11) Bad luck :-(

Answer (score 0):

I don't have eToken so I can't help you more.

First check that you have all the software and settings in place - see http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.com/2011/09/using-smart-card-as-keystore-in-java.html for more or less complete list.

If it's OK, consider trying different driver i.e. opensource instead of proprietary or vice versa.  It could make difference.